# What word should I use to describe a kid who has pooped in their underwear?

Tags: single-word-requests, expressions, slang

I have seen some kids who can't go to the restroom in time and their poops stain on their underwear. I would like to know what word I can use to describe this situation?

Answer (score 15):

I'm probably going to regret this, but the vulgar and casual expression you are looking for is [skid marks](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=skid%20marks), the bane of laundry day.

Comment: Rather than being vulgar, its a polite euphemism used by housewives/househusbands to discuss their laundry problems.

Comment: Alternatively, a "racing stripe".

Comment: Adidas comes to mind

Answer (score 10):

**[Encopresis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encopresis)** is the medical term to describe it.

Comment: The adjective form is *encopretic*.

Answer (score 7):

Pejoratives:

- *smartypants* — a kid too smart for his/her pants
- *poopypants* — a kid who either really has no control, or acts like one who has no control, over his/her digestive egress

Answer (score 4):

I would say if there was poop in the underwear the one word I would use to describe them is **stinky**.

Answer (score 1):

I would say "soiled themselves" is a better way to say it.

Comment: It's expected that definitions from reliable sources are given here.